# Regular Expression of a specific Date format

Tags: regex, oracle

I need help in forming a regular expression of a date to match YYYYMMDD format. Below are the details:

Input Validation:  The value entered is length of 8 and all numeric.  The
first character is a 1 or 2.  The 5th & 6th character are between 01 and 12,
the last two characters are between 01 and 31

I tried it below expression but cannot understand how we can provide the value ranges like 1-12 for months and 1-31 for days.

```
SELECT 'P' from dual where REGEXP_LIKE ('122412','^[1][2][0-9]{2}[1|12]$');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag the DB engine you're using please, thanks (which I think is Oracle, but you surely know better).

Comment: And btw you really do not want regexes to check *ranges*. Try with bigger/smaller than operators.

Comment: M0skit0 - I am using Oracle

Comment: Then tag it: edit your question and add the relevant tag for Oracle DB. Also to refer to a user, you use it like @user3561229

Comment: I believe I tag it correct. My question is related to Regular Expression (RegEx) and not related to Oracle DB. However, RegEx will be executed on Oracle database.

Comment: @user3561229: There are variations in regular expression engines, so the **specific** one you're using is in fact relevant. You're using the one provided by Oracle's database, which has specific features that differ from other engines. Instead of arguing, please [edit] your question and supply the proper tag as requested.

Comment: You're wrong. Not all regex engines are the same. Each DB engine might handle your regex differently or allow different possible solutions that might not work in Oracle.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
^[12][0-9]{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WyytEzoGZRuFKFFQ)

**WARNING**

It's not good idea to use regex for that, since it will pass invalid values like `20140229`, `20140431`, etc. Check @Ben's answer for proper way.

**If you want to validate datetime and cannot create functions in Oracle as in @Ben's answer (don't have access/privileges)**

Then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT 'P'
FROM DUAL
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ('20140229','^[12][0-9]{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$')
      AND '20140229' <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(SUBSTR('20140229', 1, 6) || '01', 'YYYYMMDD')), 'YYYYMMDD');
```

You do substitute `20140229` with column name.

Comment: `20140231`... nuff said

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Yes, and `20140229`, and `20140431`, ... so what? OP requested such pattern. If anybody requests you for time pattern, are you going to teach him about `leap seconds`?

Comment: (leap seconds - Yes, if it's relevant to their problem). In this case, however, the OP is trying to just validate a date, and they have (incorrectly) assumed regex is the best solution. Offer a regex solution, by all means (I didn't downvote!) but I would at least explain its limitations.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Ok, added a warning :)

Comment: Actually [Ben's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23504233/898478) is the real correct answer here.

Comment: Nothing, your answer is correct, but Ben's answer is better because checking dates with a regex is not a good idea

Comment: @m0skit0 If you notice I check for validity of date after regex check. And it doesn't require you to create any function.

Comment: Then why use regex? The point here is that checking dates with regexes is not a good idea. People learn regexes then try to apply this to all problems. This is a wrong approach. You should not try to use only tools you know, but you need to try to find the **right** tool for the job. And regexes are not for checking valid dates :)

Comment: @m0skit0 There are multiple possible situations, including the one when you don't have permissions to create functions. In this one I need first to validate against regex to be able to extract year and month for further validation. Also imagine if you just need to execute the query once, there is no point in function creation in such case (as example, migration script for data).

Comment: That's why your answer got one vote (likely from who accepted it) and Ben's 5, I see... Again: the point is showing how to do this the right way, not just answering any question no matter what. If OP specifies his limitations, we can help better, but since no limitation is specified, then you should show the correct way of doing it.

Comment: @m0skit0 Still I don't see what's wrong with my answer in current state. I added check for date validity later, that's the reason it didn't get any votes.

Comment: @m0skit0 Let me quote Treb from meta: [But I would consider also to answer the actual question, too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8893)

Comment: Who said it's wrong? As I said: *"Nothing, your answer is correct, but Ben's answer is better"*. If it was wrong it would have been downvoted.

Comment: And from the link you quoted: *"I think it's a valid answer, provided that you explain why the OP shouldn't do it (which you did in the question you gave as an example). But I would consider also to answer the actual question, too."* This is why Ben's answer is better: it explains why he shouldn't do it that way and shows an answer to the question the right way. Anyway, this discussion leads nowhere, enjoy your correct answer and have a good day!

Answer (score 6):

This is a bad idea. The *only* way to validate that a date is correct is to attempt to convert it into a date. If the conversion fails then it's not a date; if it's successful then it *might* be. Dates are far too complex for a regular language to parse.

So, create a function that converts it into a date; you can make if far more generic than you have here, so it can then be reused for other purposes:

```
create or replace function validate_date (
     PDate in varchar2
   , PDateFormat in varchar2
     ) return date is
begin
   return to_date(PDate, PDateFormat);
exception when others then
   return null;
end;
```

This returns a date if it's able to validate that the date and date format match, otherwise returns NULL if there's any error. Your query then becomes:

```
select 'P' from dual where validate_date('20140506', 'yyyymmdd') is not null
```